# Can I specify the Standard Error of the Mean (SEM) with the plus minus sign?

Tags: mean, standard-error

Can I specify the Standard Error of the Mean (SEM) with the plus minus sign?

Let's say I found a 1.34 SEM and the mean is 24.

Can I write: the mean of the population is 24 ± 1.34?

Comment: Thats seems to be done in some fields, but the best is that you state your conventions.